# How to control an items inventory with n... optional attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on an inventory project where there will be an item table to hold a general item reference, then there will be an options table, this will allow for custom attributes to be defined, such as size, color, etc. This part is fairly straight forward, where I'm having trouble is how I'd monitor the inventory.

For example, if you're allowed to create infinite options, you'd have a factorial set of rows for inventory. For example, Item A has options for size and color. You'd need to list the inventory for each size of each color. I'm not sure how I'd design that table properly for efficient queries. Am I taking a poor approach to this?

Here's my current proposed structure:

```
Items
id | name  | timestamp | and so on
1  | Shirt | ....

options
id | itemID | optionGroup (for templating) | label | Display (also for templating)
1  | 1      | Size                         | Large | Large
2  | 1      | Size                         | Small | Small
3  | 1      | Color                        | Blue  | 0000ff
4  | 1      | Color                        | Red   | ff0000
```

In this simple example, I'd need inventory records for 4 different items. If I add one more options, it'll multiply quickly. I'm also not sure the best way to save these results. I don't want to save a serialised block of values because then I'm not sure the best way to query them, or if I can. I'm a bit lost on my next best step and would love some ideas.

Comment: a very interesting problem.  here's my brain dump: you might consider utilizing separate product catalog and inventory tables. also, the point when a product is sold or removed from inventory is an event or trigger - where, and how, you store qty on hand  can be updated while handling this event.  I would be more likely to create some sort of inventory grouping methodology that allows for a parent/child relationship than I would track inventory for each attribute.  If you do use attributes, make some sort of flag that indicates that it's an inventory tracked attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You need two new tables.

One table specifies all the different products, with their combinations of options.

```
productID optionID
1           1
1           3
2           2
2           3
3           1
3           4
```

In the above, product 1 is a large, blue shirt, product 2 is a small, blue shirt, and product 3 is a large, red shirt. I think the product IDs here correspond to what vendors call SKU numbers.

Then you have an inventory table that records the quantity of each product.

```
productID   quantity
1               10
2               15
3               5
```

So `inventory` doesn't need to be duplicated for each option.